# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "merken" und "sich erinnern"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "sich erinnern" und "merken"?

Z. B.: Ich höre ein neues Wort und sage:

> Ich werde mich daran erinnern.

oder

> Ich merke (mir?) das.

Auf English würde ich sagen: "I will remember that".

Oder z. B.

> Das ist ja wichtig. Ich muss mir das merken.

oder

> Das ist ja wichtig. Ich werde mich daran erinnern.

Oder es gibt ein Wort, das ich immer wieder vergesse. Sage ich:

> Manno, ich kann mich niemals daran erinnern.

oder

> Manno, ich merke das nie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich versuche im Folgenden, die verschiedenen Phrasen, die man mit **sich etw. merken** und **sich erinnern** bilden kann, mit anderen Worten zu erklären.
Bedenke, die Konnotation in einem gegebenen Kontext kann leicht variieren oder gar komplett abweichen. Ist eine Aussage zum Beispiel ironisch gemeint, so kann genau das Gegenteil gemeint sein, oder es wird schlicht Desinteresse ausgedrückt.
Aber jetzt zum Eigentlichen:

> Ich werde mir das merken.
>   Ich merke mir das.

Ich speichere die Information jetzt ab, so dass ich in der Zukunft diese abrufen kann.

> Ich werde mich daran erinnern.

Zu einem (unbestimmten) Zeitpunkt in der Zukunft werde ich es noch wissen. Ich werde in der Lage sein, diese Information abzurufen. Dies impliziert in der Regel, dass ich es mir jetzt merken werde.

> Ich muss mir das merken.

Ich möchte unbedingt diese Information abspeichern.

> Ich kann mich nicht daran erinnern.

Ich habe es vergessen. Ich habe diese Information vielleicht mal abgespeichert (= ich hatte es mir gemerkt), aber leider ist sie verloren gegangen.

> Ich kann mich nie daran erinnern.

Ich vergesse es immer und immer wieder.

> Ich merke mir das nie.
>   Das merke ich mir nie.

Ich kann diese Information (zum wiederholten Male) nicht abspeichern.
Oder: Das ist so komplex, ich werde mit Sicherheit nicht in der Lage sein, diese Information abzuspeichern.

Bezüglich deiner Beispiele kommt es ganz drauf an, was du beschreiben möchtest. Hörst du ein neues Wort, so kannst du beides sagen: "Ich merke mir das" oder "Ich werde mich daran erinnern". Der Bedeutungsunterschied sollte hoffentlich mit meinen Beschreibungen oben erkennbar sein.

---

Genau wie im Englischen kannst du *vergessen* (*to forget*) verwenden:

> Ich werde es nicht vergessen. (I won't forget it.)
>   Ich vergesse es ständig. (I always forget it.)

Comment: Danke :) Das ist sehr komplett und hilfreich.

Comment: sich merken = to memorize, to commit to memory; sich an etwas erinnern = to recall.

Answer (score 8):

Merken bezieht sich meist auf die Zukunft, erinnern auf die Vergangenheit.

Ich **merke** mir jetzt etwas für später, ich **erinnere** mich jetzt an etwas von früher.

Oder ich **merke** mir jetzt etwas, damit ich mich später daran **erinnern** kann.

Comment: Okay ich verstehe. Aber kannst du mir bitte sagen, welcher Satz in den Beispielen richtig ist?

Comment: Alles sind korrekte Beispiele. Es kommt immer auf den Fall an - erinnerst Du dich an etwas, was schon war, oder merkst Du dir etwas, was grade passiert.

Comment: Okay vielen Danke :)

Answer (score 3):

Ich merke, dass ein Teil der Frage unbeantwortet geblieben ist: Nämlich der, der in diesem Zitat steckt:

> Ich merke (mir?) das.

"Etwas merken" und "sich etwas merken" sind zwei unterschiedliche Dinge.

"Etwas merken" bedeutet, dass man auf eine Sache aufmerksam wird. "Ich merke das." bedeutet, dass der Sprecher es mitbekommt, es bemerkt. Also zum Beispiel:

> Glaub ja nicht, Du könntest dich heimlich davonmachen. Ich merke das.

Und der ebenfalls in der Frage verwendete Satz:

> Manno, ich merke das nie.

bedeutet, dass der Sprecher etwas Bestimmtes nie mitbekommt. Das englische Pendant wäre "to notice".

"Sich etwas merken" hingegen bedeutet, dass man sich eine Tatsache einprägt, um sich später wieder daran zu erinnern. "Ich merke mir das." heißt also, dass der Sprecher sich später daran erinnern will. Also zum Beispiel:

> Erwarte nicht, dass ich es vergesse. Ich merke mir das.

Was also eigentlich beim letzten Beispielsatz in der Frage gemeint war, ist:

> Manno, ich merke mir das nie.